# Why List<Boolean> can store other object in variable (Mybatis)

Tags: java, spring, generics, mybatis

I wrote this code.

```
List<Boolean> result = testNtxMapper.selectTestObjects(testObject);

@Repository public interface TestNtxMapper { 
  ArrayList<Boolean> selectTestObjects(TestObject testObject); 
}

public class TestObject {

    private Integer blogEntryId = 0;
    private Integer entryState;
    private Integer entryCategory;
    private Integer userId;
    private String entryTitle;
    private String entryBody;
    private String entryDate;
    private Date createdAt;
    private Date updatedAt;

}
```

It should error because resultType is testObject.

```
<select id="selectTestObjects" resultType="testObject" parameterType="testObject">
```

But it has no errors and return normally.

```
result = {ArrayList@8362}  size = 1
0 = {TestObject@8389} "{"TestObject":{"sort":"null", "page":"null", "size":"null", "q":"null", "qMap":{}, "blogEntryId":"120", "entryState":"5", "entryCategory":"5", "userId":"5", "entryTitle":"llllll2", "entryBody":"vvvvvv", "entryDate":"20170315", "createdAt":Mon Apr 10 13:56:36 ICT 2017, "updatedAt":null}}"
```

Who can explain the matter ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: could you provide the signature of the method `testNtxMapper.selectTestObjects();` please?

Comment: can you give code in your mapper file . and inheritance hierarchy of testObject

Comment: it just mapper interface @Repository
public interface TestNtxMapper {
    ArrayList<Boolean> selectTestObjects(TestObject testObject);
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generics are compile time only. No matter what is declared it's internally casted. The example to illustrate how it happens.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class GenericTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Boolean> booleanList;

        List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<>();
        intList.add(42);

        List objects = intList;
        booleanList = objects;
        System.out.println(booleanList);
    }
}
```